# Symfony 3 use parameters in class that is not a service

Tags: parameters, symfony

I have a service that instantiates other classes.

I would like to parametrize a `$url` variable in those classes (different URL by class).

How could I access a parameter from a class that is not a service?

I could make those classes a service, but it would only be because of parameters, because they should not be stand alone services.

How could I solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your problem, and this could be due to the fact that you didn't provide any code, but in order to call a method with params in any controller class or anywhere else in you bundle, you just need to provide the namespace of that directory you need. Eg; if the method resides in `AppBundle/Classes/Helper.php`, then in this file you will have a `namespace AppBundle\Classes` declaration. Then in controller: `use AppBundle\Classes\Helper`, and inside any method: `$helper = new Helper(); $helper->methodName($url, $param1, $param2, ...);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access parameters in a class you need to inject the Container (not a good idea because, it will inject the entire Container just for parameters) or just inject the concerned parameters directly, right ? Like you said, it's necessary to declare your class as a service to use these parameters. If you think it is heavy to declare your class as a service to access these parameters, why don't you use [Lazy Services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/lazy_services.html) ?

Comment: I guess Lazy Services could work... do you know if it works when using an array of services injected? i.e: The service has a $clients array param which is composed of other services

Comment: @JorgeeFG You should use  [Tagged services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html) , just tag all the services you want to inject in another one with the same id. And then create a [Compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html) to inject all the tagged services in the service you want